# How to use dpkg of busybox

Tags: busybox

I'm trying to install pkg in a limited space embedded system.
I use busybox's dpkg.
To let dpkg work, I just touch a file

```
touch /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But, it still can not work.

```
$dpkg -i ntpdate_4.2.4p4+dfsg-8lenny3_sh4.deb                           
dpkg: package ntpdate depends on netbase, which is not installed or flagged to be installed
```

How to flag the netbase as installed?
I mean cheat to let dpkg treat it could install.

Answer (score 1):

You need dpkg to ignore dependencies, use the following command:

```
dpkg -i --force-depends mypackage.deb
```

Or, in case you have more problems arising, use:

```
dpkg -i --force-all mypackage.deb
```

But be warned, package dependencies are almost always ***true*** dependencies, as in, the program might be linked against them.

And using the above commands, will install the package fine, but dpkg will label it as broken.

Comment: Hi @Waleed, --force-depends doesn't help with a completely uninitialised dpkg system. --force-all is not recognised by busybox flavor of dpkg. I've updated the question to reflect that. Kind regards, Rob

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be to use debootstrap anyway. Here's a howto https://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/arm/apds03.html.en

The process I managed to use is with the --foreign parameter, which creates a root filesystem ready to be bootstrapped. My command:

```
debootstrap --foreign --arch amd64 --variant minbase \
   --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/debian-keyring.gpg \
   jessie debstaged

cd debstaged
tar -czf ../iso/debstaged.tar.gz *
cd ..
```

The root filesystem tar/gzipped is in my iso folder that I use to create a bootable CD

Once I boot the CD which only has a minimalist busybox initramfs, I can simply untar that filesystem and complete the installation:

```
mount /dev/sr0 /mnt
mkdir /tmp/root
mount -t tmpfs debroot /tmp/root
cd /tmp/root
tar -xzf /mnt/debstaged.tar.gz
umount /mnt
chroot . /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
```

At this point, I have a ready configured debian system root in /tmp/root.

The answer is obviously incomplete, but if we could figure which files are necessary and manage to debinify the busybox system, there could be a way. This resource was quite helpful as well - http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2014-June/081017.html

I should be able to switch to the new root like that, but my kernel doesn't have devtmpfs which is required by systemd init:

```
echo > /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug
umount /proc
umount /sys

exec switch_root -c /dev/console /tmp/root /sbin/init
```

Kind regards, Rob